# Save Docker container data

Tags: python, docker, redis, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to save the data of python app in redis but when I stop the docker-compose file the data is removed and when I again run the docker-compose file it starts from the start. I want to save the data of the container and whenever it starts it starts from where it left when the container exited. For example when I exited the container it shows `Hello World! I have been seen b'6' times.` and when i restart the container it should start from `Hello World! I have been seen b'6' times.`

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  nginx_app:
    image: nginx:latest
    depends_on:
      - flask_app
    volumes:
      - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - 8082:80
    networks:
      - my_project_network

  flask_app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    expose:
      - 5000
    depends_on:
      - redis_app
    networks:
      - my_project_network

  redis_app:
    image: redis:latest
    command: redis-server --requirepass 1234
    volumes:
      - ./redis-vol:/data
    expose:
      - 6379
    networks:
      - my_project_network

networks:
  my_project_network:
    external: true
```

python file:

```
from flask import Flask
from redis import Redis
app = Flask(__name__)
redis = Redis(host='redis_app', port=6379, password='123a')
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    redis.incr('hits')
    return 'Hello World! I have been seen %s times.' % redis.get('hits')
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

Comment: You need to learn about -> https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/

Comment: can we do it with data-volume?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a volume to your redis service.

As I remember, the internal path for this redis image is `/data`. Just mount this volume in your docker-compose.

Do not forget to add `--appendonly yes` to your redis command.

Comment: Can you please verify the internal path? or provide a volume line that I can add to redis?

Comment: Read the paragraph titled `start with persistent storage` here https://hub.docker.com/_/redis

Comment: `volumes:
      - ./redis-vol:/data` I have added this line but still can't save the data. I have updated the question and added this line to the question

Comment: what is the content of your redis-vol ? It should contains the redis database file after the first run.

Comment: I am new to this and haven't work with redis. Can you please tell me what is the path to it?

Comment: when you add your volume to docker-compose, you mount the local `./redis-vol` path to the `/data` path inside your redis container. When you start the redis container, it should create its database in this path. So, locally, you should see a file inside the `./redis-vol` path. I forgot to tell you, sorry. You have to enable redis persistence also by adding the flag `--appendonly yes` the same way you added `--requirepass wahaj123a` See https://redis.io/topics/persistence

Comment: Oh I see so I just have to add `--appendonly yes` to the redis?

Comment: Yes :) And you should see the file appear in `./redis-vol`.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation on "volumes", you will find:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/

A Kubernetes volume, on the other hand, has an explicit lifetime - **the same as the Pod that encloses it.** Consequently, a volume outlives any Containers that run within the Pod, and data is preserved across Container restarts. Of course, **when a Pod ceases to exist, the volume will cease to exist, too.** Perhaps more importantly than this, Kubernetes supports many types of volumes, and a Pod can use any number of them simultaneously.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/

IN short, you need to change to persistent volumes.

Comment: I haven't work with kurbernetes before, trying to do it with docker-compose volumes but I think I am not giving the path to redis right

Comment: -1: The asker isn't asking about kubernetes, and bringing in kubernetes to solve a problem which can be solved with normal Docker volumes is an unnecessary complication.